# Dynamic CRM online

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am using dynamic crm for my order. I have been trying to accomplish another task (submitting price list from my own excel document and not the crm excel template), now it so happens that when I make an order, it does not show in my Opportunities. Can someone help me with this issue. From my view it is like the Quotes are not linked to the opportunities

thanx

Comment: You have to either create the Quote from the associated view in the Opportunity record or specify the Opportunity in the Quote itself for the Quote to show up in the Opportunity's associated view. I can't recall any relation between this, and a data import job. Also, an Order is different from a Quote, I suggest editing the question clarifying the steps you're following in your business process. Also, as usual, make sure customizations are solid.

Comment: They create an opportunity first.

Then once they get pricing from a supplier they do a quote FROM that opportunity screen.

The quotes normally showed up on the opportunity view, but now it doesn’t any more.

Comment: Check the `opportunityid` field in the quote, and make sure the View is correct (maybe the quotes are being filtered out of it?).

Comment: Yeah, the opportunityid on Quote is the same as the opportunityid on tbl Opportunity. I ran a SQL statement to check for this in my CRMdb, this brings me to believe that the problem may be on the App its self, I just dont understand what could have gone wrong for it not to display the Quote on the Opportunity